# Is it possible to run the SQL Browser service on a specific IP address on Linux

Tags: sql-server

When running my configuration of SQL Server on Linux there are two ports being listened on, 1433 and 1434:

```
# netstat -plnt | grep sqlservr
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1434          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      43/sqlservr         
tcp        0      0 172.28.24.216:1433      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      43/sqlservr         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:1434                :::*                    LISTEN      43/sqlservr         
#
```

I would like to either disable the service running on 1434 (I don't think this is possible) or change the address it binds to instead of localhost.

My understanding is that port 1434 is for the "SQL Browser service" however I am unable to find a way to disable or change the address on which the service binds.

This is my current configuration:

```
# cat /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf
[sqlagent]
enabled = false

[network]
ipaddress = 172.28.24.216

#
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP 1434 port used by default for Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC)
SQL Browser Service use UDP 1434 instead.

You can't disable default DAC listener.
But you can force SQL Server to change default listener to choose port dynamically.
If port 1434 will be locked by another process when Database Engine starts, service try to register DAC to random dynamic port

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).